# How do I turn text-searchable PDFs in a folder into non-searchable without losing quality?

Tags: python, pdf

I need to turn searchable PDFs into non-shearchable ones, but every attempt I made so far with Python made the quality drop drastically, making them difficult to read.

I tried converting them into jpg and then back to PDF, and I tried using PyMuPDF. They had similar quality at the end of the process, even if the former took much longer.

Ideally, I would like to make a Python script that gets all the pdf in a folder and converts them.

I have to shamefully admit I did not understand how to install and use poppler.
The only similar question I found was about ghostscript.

Comment: Bitmaps will always be lower quality than text that can be rendered at any size and resolution / dots-per-inch.  JPEG is lossy with a slider for the quality, with a trade-off between quality and file size.  Did you try increasing the quality setting or dots-per-inch settings for the JPEG rendering?

Comment: Also keep in mind that someone can make the PDF searchable again by feeding it into OCR software, so do you really need to do this?

Comment: @DaveS thanks for your comments. I didn't think about that, I might try. And yes, unfortunately I must. The reason is who is going to receive these files might copy and paste the text if it's searchable, but they will most likely not go through the process of making it searchable just for that.

Comment: Good point, if the content is supposed to be accessible, this will break that.  In some countries that might result in fines or lawsuits for violating regulations like the ADA (Americans with Disabilities Act)

Comment: No, the target does not include people with screen readers, it is for a test we must do at work. We know people might cheat if the PDF is searchable (not getting into details here), and we also know they probably will not turn the files back into searchable nor probably have the skills to do so.